# How to ignore message in the queue?

Tags: winapi

I am creating application with win32 GUI and I tried blocking and ignoring some window messages of the message queue in my message loop. For it, I tried this following code:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    if (msg.message != WM_... /*to complete with messages to block*/) DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

But it does not work and I can not understand why. Normally, except some particular messages, all messages pass by the message loop, so the messages that I block should be ignored! What is not wrong with my code? Mayby I shoud try to rethink my message loop?

Thanks for reading and your help.

Comment: Can you post a [minimally reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example which is more precise? Which message? What does "does not work" mean precisely?

Comment: You don't ignore them in the loop. You ignore them in the Window Procedure. If the Window Procedure doesn't tell the queue the message is handled it will continue to be propagated.

Comment: Please read the documentation on [message routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#message-routing).

Comment: You are able to intercept queued messages like this. It's the synchronous non queued messages that are dispatched by GetMessage that you won't be seeing.